# Service delegate throws an "LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session"

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I know there are plenty of "could not initialize proxy - no Session" questions but I did not found any answer to my problem.

So the problem is, when I delegate `fetchLazy` method, it throws an above mentioned exception. Here is a simplified version of my service class:

**Service**

```
public abstract class Service<S extends Service<S,E>, E extends Entity> {
    @PersistenceContext private EntityManager entityManager;

    // person = personService.fetchLazy(person, Person::getCompany); OK
    public E fetchLazy(E entity, Function<E,?> proxyMapper) {
        E attachedEntity = entityManager.find(entity.getClass(), entity.getId());
        Object proxy = proxyMapper.apply(attachedEntity);
        if (!Hibernate.isInitialized(proxy)) { Hibernate.initialize(proxy); }
        return attachedEntity;
    }

    // person = personService.fetch(person).lazy(Person::getCompany); EXCEPTION
    public FetchBuilder fetch(E entity) { return new FetchBuilder((S) this, entity); }

    public class FetchBuilder {
        private final S service; private final E entity;
        LazyFetchBuilder(E e, S s) { this.entity = e; this.service = s; }
        public E lazy(E entity, Function<E,?> proxyMapper) {
             return service.fetchLazy(entity, proxyMapper); // DELEGATE
        }
    }
}
```

**PersonService**

```
@Stateless
public class PersonService extends Service<PersonService,Person> { ... }
```

**PersonBean**

```
@Named @ViewScoped
public class PersonBean implements Serializable {
    @EJB private PersonService personService;

    @PostConstruct public void init()  {
        person = personService.getById(id);
        person = personService.fetchLazy(person, Person::getCompany); // OK
        person = personService.fetch(person).lazy(Person::getCompany); // EXCEPTION
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume this service is a Java EE or Spring transactional service. Declarative transactions are  proxy-based. When you get an instance of a service using dependency injection and call a transactional method, you in fact call the method of a transactional proxy that wraps the service:

```
client ----------> transactional proxy -----------> service
                    - start the transaction
                    - call the service
                    - commit
                    -return the value returned by the service
```

When you call `fetchLazy()`, everything works fine:

- a transaction is started,
- then the entity is found using the entity manager and its company proxy is initialized,
- then the transaction is committed
- then you get the entity with its initialized company.

When you call `fetch()`, here's what happens

- a transaction is started,
- a FetchBuilder is constructed
- then the transaction is committed
- then you get the FetchBuilder

This transaction is actually useless, since you never use the entity manager.

Now what happens when you call `fetch()` on the returned builder? It calls `fetchLazy` on the `service` instance variable of the FetchBuilder. This `service` is an instance of the actual service instance, not an instance of the proxy that wraps the service instance, since you initialized it with `this`, from the service instance itself. You're thus bypassing the proxy, and these is thus no transaction wrapping the call to `find()` and the intialization of the company.